# How to append and pop from a list parallely in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to run two functions, namely **recorder()** and **transmitter()** parallelly. Recorder() function adds a random string to the **packets** list every one second, while the transmitter function pops the first string in the **packets** every two seconds. I need to run the two functions parallelly and independent of each other. Is there a way of doing it?

I thought of using the asyncio library for this. But I am not sure whether I am correct.
Any help will be appreciated.

```py
import random
import string
import asyncio

packets = []

async def recorder():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    #Generating random string
    res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 5))
    packets.append(res)
    print(f"Added {res}")
    
async def transmitter():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    ans = packets.pop(0)
    print(f"Got {ans}")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to accomplish this in Python: the threading module in the standard library and the asyncio module also in the standard library. Which one you should use is beyond the scope of this question and could fill volumes, but it's worth reading up a little bit on the tradeoffs.

For asyncio, there is an [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) class which allows coroutines to safely pop and append from the same queue.

For threading, there is a [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) class which can be shared across threads and allows concurrent threads to safely append and pop to the queue.

Note that if you need last-in, first-out semantics there are also LIFO versions of both queues in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

With your queue adding at a rate of 1/sec and emptying at a rate of 0.5/sec it will grow and cause issues. You either need to stop filling at some point or empty faster, I've set it to immediately empty as this is simpler.

The other change that is worth making is to avoid using `packets` as a global variable, rather I have passed the queue as an argument. This makes testing with something like [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) a little easier.

```
import random
import string
import asyncio

async def recorder(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        #Generating random string
        res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 5))
        queue.put_nowait(res)
        print(f"Added {res}")
    
async def transmitter(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        ans = await queue.get()
        print(f"Got {ans}")

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.create_task(recorder(queue))
    asyncio.create_task(transmitter(queue))
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The output looks like the following with `Got` appearing really fast after `Added`.

```
Added RBO4A
Got RBO4A
Added P4WPT
Got P4WPT
Added 9TNYU
Got 9TNYU
```